# Как отслеживать какие SQL запросы чаще и дольше всего выполняются?

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Как и чем можно можно отслеживать и оценивать работу базы данных MySQL, в частности, какие SQL запросы идут чаще всего и за какое время они выполняются?

Answer (score 2):

Отслеживать SQL-запросы в MySQL можно, включив логгирование. Чтобы разрешить логгирование запустите `mysqld` с опциями `--log[=имя_файла]` или `-l [имя_файла]`. А уже имея лог, можно строить статистику, чтобы оценивать время и частоту различных запросов.